# Extract android phone contacts using java desktop application

Tags: java, android

I need a little help. I'm thinking to create a **java desktop application in which i want to fetch all the contacts from the attached android phone**. I searched a lot but didn't find helpful material. Please give me some suggestions.
 I can use multiple languages or OS. Is it possible? If yes then help me how i can achieve this, any API to work with or any other materials.
**I want to do this without installing any application on android.** like professional software do.
It would be a duplicate question but i didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are roughly:

1. Write a desktop application which:

   1. Can access the Android phone as a MTP / mass storage device and read files from it
   2. Knows how to parse contact data files (see below)
2. Write an Android application which:

   1. Configures the phone to be used as a MTP / mass storage device;
   2. Can read contact data ([see Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html));
   3. Serializes that to a format known to both applications.

So, when the user plugs in the phone, they launch the mobile app. It spits out a data file with the contact data, and the computer is looking for it. When it sees it (via the MTP / mass storage), it does whatever it is going to do.

On both sides (mobile and desktop) you could potentially watch for USB plug events. You could also potentially use an inotify on the desktop side when watching the storage.

Comment: But can we do it without making/installing any android app. like professional software make backup by just using desktop application.